# Anyone get python26 install in Snow Leopard via Macports?

Tags: python, osx-snow-leopard, macports

I got build error after run in Snow Leopard (MacPort v.1.8.0)

```
sudo port install python26
```

any workaround please?

```
Error: Target org.macports.build returned: shell command " cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_lang_python26/work/Python-2.6.2" && /usr/bin/make all MAKE="/usr/bin/make CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2" " returned error 2
Command output: if test ""; then \
        /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -o Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Python  -dynamiclib \
            -isysroot "" \
            -all_load libpython2.6.a -Wl,-single_module \
            -install_name /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Python \
            -compatibility_version 2.6 \
            -current_version 2.6; \
        else \
        /usr/bin/libtool -o Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Python -dynamic  libpython2.6.a \
             -lSystem -lSystemStubs -arch_only i386 -install_name /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Python -compatibility_version 2.6 -current_version 2.6 ;\
    fi
/usr/bin/install -c -d -m 755  \
        Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Resources/English.lproj
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 Mac/Resources/framework/Info.plist \
        Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Resources/Info.plist
ln -fsn 2.6 Python.framework/Versions/Current
ln -fsn Versions/Current/Python Python.framework/Python
ln -fsn Versions/Current/Headers Python.framework/Headers
ln -fsn Versions/Current/Resources Python.framework/Resources
/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -L/opt/local/lib -u _PyMac_Error Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Python -o python.exe \
            Modules/python.o \
             -ldl      
ld: warning: in Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Python, file is not of required architecture
Undefined symbols:
  "_PyMac_Error", referenced from:
  "_Py_Main", referenced from:
      _main in python.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [python.exe] Error 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are apparently problems with Python via Macports on Snow Leopard, see [this thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/9fm2w/snow_leopard_macports_warning_python_ports_broken/). From there, [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/9fm2w/snow_leopard_macports_warning_python_ports_broken/c0cl7dn)'s an entry suggesting a way to get it working.